# Use Environment variable in job description

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to set dynamically a job description with a global environment variable.
But I cannot use `$MYVAR` or `${MYVAR}`.

Does anybody have an idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: Thanks for the correction ISanych and pardon my french :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post the details of what you are doing and the outputs you see in a way that someone could reproduce the same behavior. Are you using a build step / plugin? Are you trying to set the build description by POSTing to the Jenkins API?

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution, I am using the ["Anything Goes" formatter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=60915753) plugin.

In my job description, i'm using :

```
<iframe src="http:/JENKINS_URL/Docs/DocsJenkins/MY_DATA.html"></iframe>
```

I created an alias in IIS referencing a folder with some html pages. And i'm setting dynamicaly this pages with my global enviromnent variables.

Hope this tricks can help somebody else.

Comment: Hi, trying to follow your steps here... So you have a separate web server running for that purpose and you refer to its HTML pages from inside of your description boxes using `iframe` tag, right? Is there a way to do the same using built-in Jenkins web server? And could you please give more details on "*setting dynamically this pages with my global environment variables*" - how do you provide global vars to those pages?

Answer (score -1):

You should install [Environment Injector Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin).

1. After installation, go to your job configuration page,then

> Build Environment ==> Inject environment variables to the build process ==> Properties Content

2. Define your environment with KEY=VALUE format:
   [image]
3. Then, this variable can be accessed by surrounded by `${}`
   [image]

Comment: Hi. I'm trying to set my Job description and not a build description.